# Should there be fewer "require moderator" flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, declined-flags

Recently I was prohibited from flagging since too many flags were declined. When I reviewed my flags I found this:

[image]

Referring to this question:
*[How do I make text inside the title tag animate using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23731357/2407212)*

It was clearly not a duplicate even though five people flagged it as such, and a moderator declined my claim. When I asked about it in chat the question got re-opened and they explained the reason for the decline is likely that moderators don't like to be bothered for such petty issues.

I never even realised before that this was a special moderator flag until that time and hence my question:

Should perhaps the flags under the moderator category be re-evaluated?

Comment: Re-evaluated to what? The wiki summary for [tag:feature-request] says: "Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, [prove](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying) to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature."

Comment: Pedantic note: Flag and vote to close are not the same thing. On-topic: If you edit the question, it will be put into the review queue where others may vote on it. It appears that bringing attention to it in chat worked as well.

Comment: ***All*** custom flag reasons go to moderators, while the preset ones may go to queues or may go to moderators depending on the flag.  So it has to be handled by a moderator if you use a custom flag.

Comment: The only way you could have raised a custom flag is if you went through the flag dialog and specifically chose *"other (needs ♦ moderator attention) This question needs a moderator's attention. Please describe exactly what's wrong."* It spells out quite clearly the nature of the custom flag and who exactly receives and reviews it. This description is present even if "other" was the only choice available in the dialog. The diamond is pretty hard to miss too.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "less 'require moderator' flags"? Fewer situations where moderator flags should be made available, reduced daily flag quota, or less work for us to do?

Answer (score 5):

In the help center for [reopening questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions), it enumerates the ways that you can get a question reopened. To address your specific concern, it states:

> Additionally, you can:
>
> 3. Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, explain why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators
>      do reconsider their decisions.
>
> ...
>
> Moderators may close or reopen any question with a single vote.

Your custom flag reason didn't explain *why* it should be reopened.

Of course, if you have 3000 reputation, you can vote to reopen yourself, but since you don't, you may edit the question explaining why it isn't a duplicate. [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277656/3920237):

> Quickest way to dispute a dup is to just edit in some text of the
>   form,
>
> > ... the solutions presented there won't work for [the question asker's] purposes because of *detailed and plausible reasons*.
>
> This'll automatically throw it into reopen review along with
>   sufficient information for reviewers to make a decision.

<sub>Anecdotally, I also believe that moderators are unwilling to use the super-reopen-vote and leave it to the community instead unless they have to.</sub>

Comment: "Your custom flag reason didn't explain why it should be reopened." It says "Not a duplicate" that seems pretty clear. The issue isn't though whether it is or isn't a duplicate, my question is: Why would something that seems so trivial require special moderator attention in the first place?

Comment: @Jonathan there is no flag equivalent of a reopen vote, like there are for close votes.  Such a feature has been [proposed and declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186722/can-we-have-the-ability-to-flag-for-reopening). So if you think something is wrongly closed, you did the right thing.  But "This is not a duplicate" is not an explanation of why.  You need to explain **why** it isn't a duplicate so the mod (who may not be a subject matter expert) has enough information to make an informed judgement.

Comment: @Jonathan: It doesn't. The option is there for when there is a problem that *does* warrant our attention. If there isn't, you should avoid flagging the question for any reason. If you really feel strongly about it, then psub's suggestion is sound.